# Сброс текста в TextBox при изменении ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть `ComboBox` c элементами; когда выбираю элемент выводится соответствующий список элементов. Так же есть `TextBox`, который осуществляет поиск по этому листу.

**Вопрос:** как при изменении элемента в `ComboBox` сбрасывать текст введенный в `TextBox`? Буду благодарен за ссылки на примеры.

Сам Combobox:

```xml
<ComboBox
    ItemsSource="{Binding ResourcesList}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"
    SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedResource, Mode=OneWayToSource}">
```

Сам TextBox:

```xml
<TextBox Name="RightsSearchTextBox">
```

Comment: Привяжите `Text` у текстбокса в свойству, а в сеттере `SelectedResource` выполняйте очистку этого свойства.

Comment: Благодарю! Красиво и лаконично.